# CommandExecutor not registering command with multiple args?

Tags: bukkit

I have a plugin that works with different commands throughout different classes. However, in this case when I have an argument length of 2, the command just doesn't seem to register.

```
public class FinalFrontierAdminCmds implements CommandExecutor{

    FinalFrontier get;

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String cmdLabel,
            String[] args) {

        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ff")){


            // Check if only /ff is typed
            if (args.length == 0){
                p.sendMessage("This will display help menu");
                return true;    
            }



            if (args.length == 2){

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("create")){
                    if(args[1] != null){
                        get.getConfig().set("Maps." + args[1] + ".world", p.getLocation().getWorld());
                        get.getConfig().set("Maps." + args[1] + ".x", p.getLocation().getBlockX());
                        get.getConfig().set("Maps." + args[1] + ".y", p.getLocation().getBlockY());
                        get.getConfig().set("Maps." + args[1] + ".z", p.getLocation().getBlockZ());
                        get.getConfig().set("Maps." + args[1] + ".isSet", false);

                        p.sendMessage(get.ffMsg + "You have succesfully created map " + ChatColor.GREEN + args[1] + ChatColor.YELLOW + "!");
                        return true;

                    }
                }
            }


            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Main class with onEnable and onDisable:

```
public class FinalFrontier extends JavaPlugin{

    String ffMsg = ChatColor.GREEN + "[" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Final Frontier" + ChatColor.GREEN + "]" + ChatColor.YELLOW + ": ";

    public void onEnable(){

        getConfig().addDefault("Maps.", "");
        this.getCommand("ff").setExecutor(new FinalFrontierAdminCmds());
        saveConfig();

    }

    public void onDisable(){
        saveConfig();
    }

}
```

This is the first time this happens to me. I usually do it like this, unless something has changed? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `getConfig().addDefault("Maps.", "");` throws an IllegalArgumentException error because you are trying to set an empty path (the empty path being the non-existent string after the "."). If you remove the period it will create that section correctly.

I didn't see any code in your command executor class that initializes the `get` variable. I would add the constructor (if you haven't already done so),

```
public FinalFrontierAdminCmds(FinalFrontier plugin) {
    this.get = plugin;
}
```

and update the instantiation of the object in your `onEnable()` method to reflect this change (`this.getCommand("ff").setExecutor(new FinalFrontierAdminCmds(this))`), otherwise your command executor class will throw an NPE when trying to add the values.

Last but not least I would also save the world's name (`p.getLocation().getWorld().getName()`) and not pass the world object itself to the `set` method, otherwise the config file will look something like this:

```
Maps:
  example:
     world: !!org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftWorld
       PVP: true
       ambientSpawnLimit: 15
       animalSpawnLimit: 15
       autoSave: true
       difficulty: PEACEFUL
       environment: NORMAL
       fullTime: 1100
       keepSpawnInMemory: true
       monsterSpawnLimit: 70
       thunderDuration: 32301
       thundering: false
       time: 1100
       waterAnimalSpawnLimit: 5
       weatherDuration: 56712
     //more values down here
```

With these fixes your code should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail! Really helps for now and the future!